# How to implement Scroller like iPhone 4 Video Player Frame Scroller

Tags: ios, ios4, slider, iphone

In iPhone 4 Video Player there is Frame Scroller  on the top. In this scroller when I hold touch on the screen of iPhone it expand the particular frame.

**How can I implement the scroller like that.**

Please give me direction so that I can implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the scroller by creating a custom view, and filling it with thumbnail images using the `MPMoviePlayerController's` `requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:timeOption:` method. You'll need to work out how many images fit in your view and then how many seconds apart they need to be so that you get evenly spaced out images.

As for implementing the scrubber, I'm not too sure about that. Maybe somebody else will have an idea. Check out the properties of `MPMoviePlayerController` though.